# gRPC - Deadlines vs Changing System Time

Tags: grpc

My software is running on a system that gets its system clock set arbitrarily by an external server. There are no rules or guarantees about either (a) how much of a time change occurs; and (b) how often this time change happens.

My first question: Are there best practices with regards to dealing with deadlines in this case, as deadlines are (as of now) absolute times and not durations?

My second question: If my software does not care about either delivery confirmation nor the return value of an rpc call, can I safely set the deadline to "now" or even a time in the past in order to have the rpc call return as soon as possible? I.e. If the deadline is in the past, is the outgoing payload for the rpc guaranteed to be sent?

Not that it should matter, but I'm using both the .NET and the C++ implementations of gRPC in different applications.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [gRPC doc](https://grpc.io/blog/deadlines) there is no single straight forward way to determine the best deadline. If your service is as simple as [Greeter example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/protos/helloworld.proto), 100 ms deadline will be fine. But if your service is complex for example globally-distributed or have to execute a large complex query in database then you have to consider many factors like,

- end to end latency of the whole system which can be synchronous or asynchronous.
- Application design

and many others. For recommended way to set deadline see in the [Setting a deadline](https://grpc.io/blog/deadlines) section. Also deadline count elapsed time rather than depending on system clock because system clock can be changed to backward or forward.

If your software does not care about the return value of an rpc call, you can make the call in a different thread and continue with your regular thread.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlines are absolute times, but that does not imply absolute wall clock time. They should generally use a monotonic clock which is not impacted by date/time changes by the user. grpc-java uses System.nanoTime() and C core uses CLOCK_MONOTONIC when on Linux.

If a deadline is in the past, the RPC may not be sent. gRPC does not provide "fire and forget" RPCs.